# (i).Prove that $\pi_m(n)=\pi_m(n-m)+\pi_{m-1}(n)$ without using the generating functions for $\pi_m(n)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions

Questions:

$\pi_m(n)$ is defined as the number of partitions of n in which each part is no larger than m.

(i).Prove that $\pi_m(n)=\pi_m(n-m)+\pi_{m-1}(n)$ without using the generating functions for $\pi_m(n)$.

> The generating functions for $\pi_m(n)$ is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\pi_m(n)q^n=\prod\limits_{j=1}^m \frac{1}{1-q^j}$, where $|q|<1$.

(ii). Deduce from (i) that if $F_m(q)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\pi_m(n)q^n$, then $$F_m(q)=q^mF_m(q)+F_{m-1}(q).$$

(iii) Use (ii) to prove the generating functions for $\pi_m(n)$.

My works:

**I really have no idea how to prove (i);**

(ii)

$F_{m-1}(q)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\pi_{m-1}(n)q^n$;

**I'm not sure if these steps are correct:**
$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\pi_m(n-m)q^{n}
=q^{n}(\pi_m(0-m)+\pi_m(1-m)+...+\pi_m(m-m)+\pi_m(m+1-m)+...+\pi_m(\infty-m))
=q^{m}(\pi_m(0-m)+\pi_m(1-m)+...+\pi_m(m-1-m))+q^{n}(\pi_m(m-m)+\pi_m(m+1-m)+...+\pi_m(\infty-m))
=q^{n+m}(0+...+0+\pi_m(0)+\pi_m(1)+...+\pi_m(\infty))
=q^{n+m}(\pi_m(0)+\pi_m(1)+...+\pi_m(\infty))
=q^{n+m}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\pi_m(n)=q^m F_m(q)$

Then,

$$F_m(q)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\pi_m(n)q^n=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(\pi_m(n-m)+\pi_{m-1}(n))q^n=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\pi_m(n-m)q^n+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\pi_{m-1}(n)q^n=q^m F_m(q)+F_{m-1}(q)$$
 as desire.

(iii)

We need to prove $F_m(q)=\prod\limits_{j=1}^m \frac{1}{1-q^j}$, where $|q|<1$.

$\prod\limits_{j=1}^m \frac{1}{1-q^j}=\frac{1}{1-q}\frac{1}{1-q^2}\frac{1}{1-q^3}...\frac{1}{1-q^m}=(1+q+q^2+q^3+...)(1+q^2+q^4+...)(1+q^3+q^9+...)...(1+q^n+q^{2n}+...)=1+q+(q^2+q^2)+(q^3+q^3+q^3)+...=1+1*q^1+2*q^2+3*q^3+...=\pi_m(0)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty nq^n$

Does $\pi_m(0)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty nq^n=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\pi_m(n)q^n$?

**I think I am suppose to use (ii) to prove it...but I have no idea how $q^mF_m(q)+F_{m-1}(q)=\prod\limits_{j=1}^m \frac{1}{1-q^j}.$**

> After reading the Hints given by Mike:
>
> (iii) By (ii), we know $(1-q^m)F_m(q)=F_{m-1}(q) \Rightarrow \frac{F_m(q)}{F_{m-1}(q)}=\frac{1}{1-q^m}$
>
> $\prod\limits_{j=1}^m \frac{1}{1-q^j}=\frac{1}{1-q^1}\frac{1}{1-q^2}...\frac{1}{1-q^m}=\frac{F_1(q)}{F_{0}(q)}\frac{F_2(q)}{F_{1}(q)}...\frac{F_m(q)}{F_{m-1}(q)}=\frac{F_m(q)}{F_0(q)}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\pi_m(n)q^n$
>   as desire.

Answer (score 2):

By abuse of notation, I'm also going to denote $\pi_m(n)$ also as the *set* of partitions of $n$ into parts at most $m$.

**Hint for (i)**: Seperate $\pi_m(n)$ into two sets: those partitions that have $m$ as a part, and those partitions whose parts are all strictly less than $m$. The two sets on the right are the partitions of $n-m$ into parts at most $m$ and the partitions of $n$ into parts at most $m-1$. Do you see a bijection between each pair of sets?

(ii) You're working too hard (and in your attempted proof, you added infinitely many positive numbers, so your function would diverge). $$F_m(q)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \pi_m(n) q^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \pi_{m-1}(n)q^{n} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \pi_m(n-m)q^{n}$$ As you noted, the first $m$ terms vanish from the second sum. Re-indexing, we have $$F_m(q) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \pi_{m-1}(n)q^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \pi_m(n)q^{n+m} = F_{m-1}(q) + q^m\sum_{n=0}^\infty \pi_m(n)q^{n}$$ $$= F_{m-1}(q) + q^mF_m(q)$$

**Hint for (iii)** Use induction, and rewrite (ii) as $(1-q^m)F_m(q) = F_{m-1}(q)$

Comment: Can you please explain how the sets have bijections between "those partitions that have m as a part" and "the partitions of n−m into parts at most m ----- $\pi_m(n-m)$" ? I get the other parts though..

Comment: The bijective map deletes (one of) the part(s) equal to m - giving you a partition of n-m with parts still at most m. Can you show bijectivity, knowing the map?

Comment: Sorry, I really struggled showing it...

Comment: Well, this function has an inverse: adding a part of size $m$ to your partition. Can you show that this is really it's (two-sided) inverse? If so, we have a bijection.